# How to install tensorflow C API 1.15 on Mac M1?

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I found most tutorials describing install tf C API on Mac M1 for >2 versions and not applied to earlier versions.

Comment: I don't believe you should not ask this type of questions here although welcome to SO always check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for helpfull tips on what to ask and more importantly how to better ask a question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

[**here**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/lib_package/README.md)'s a guide on how to build a version from scratch since outdated or legacy versions of software typically are harder to install especially when it comes to libraries.

You wanna search for releases on the right panel of GitHub(if you don't see it click on the repository link on the top left or just click into this hyperlink for a quick shortcut into the 1.15 version [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/v1.15.0)

I don't know however if this version is compatible with your Mac model since the mac M1 is a arm based computer so even more problems will arise